# Java Simple Tax Calculator, calling a method

Tags: java, methods, calculator

I have created a simple tax calculator that will calculate Federal and Provincial taxes for incomes less than or equal to $41,536 and this worked fine.
Now to create a method that will calculate and print the tax, this isn't working for me

Here is the code..

```
package lab4;

import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author demo
 */
public class Lab4 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    // Q4. Tax Calculation
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter your income: ");
    String userIncome=sc.nextLine();

    calculateAndPrintTax();
}       

static double calculateAndPrintTax(double userIncome)
{

    double uIncome= Double.parseDouble(userIncome);
    double federalExemption= 11327.0;
    double provincialExemption= 9863.0;
    double federalTax =  (uIncome- federalExemption) * 0.15;
    double provincialTax= (uIncome - provincialExemption) * 0.0505;
    double totalTax= federalTax + provincialTax;

    System.out.println("Your payable Federal tax is: " + federalTax);
    System.out.println("Your payable Provincial tax is: "+ provincialTax);
    System.out.println("Total payable tax is: "+ totalTax);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed some stuff and was able to compile and run the program successfully.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
// Q4. Tax Calculation
Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter your income: ");
double userIncome=sc.nextDouble();

calculateAndPrintTax(userIncome);
}       

static void calculateAndPrintTax(double userIncome)
{
double federalExemption= 11327.0;
double provincialExemption= 9863.0;
double federalTax =  (userIncome- federalExemption) * 0.15;
double provincialTax= (userIncome - provincialExemption) * 0.0505;
double totalTax= federalTax + provincialTax;

System.out.println("Your payable Federal tax is: " + federalTax);
System.out.println("Your payable Provincial tax is: "+ provincialTax);
System.out.println("Total payable tax is: "+ totalTax);
}
}
```

When you call the calculateAndPrintTax method, you have to enter parameters too, because your method asks for them. So instead of calculateAndPrintTax(); you should have calculateAndPrintTax(userIncome); because that's what the method uses to do all of its calculations. I also changed userIncome to a double to simplify the process.

You must also make calculateAndPrintTax void, and remove the double, because instead of returning any values, it prints them out instead.

Hope I could help.

Comment: Faraz, I'd love to, but I don't have enough experience points :/

Comment: Appreciate the response. the 3rd line, I am not supposed to use sc.nextDouble, yet. I need to ask the user to input a value, and then convert that value and store it into a variable. Exaple: String userIncome=sc.nextLine();
        double uIncome= Double.parseDouble(userIncome);                                    Ill get back to you on the rest though

Comment: Okay John, Your answer has worked Succcessfully, however in the beginning the only requirement of the question is that we prompt the user to enter a value, which will be stored into a string, and then we have to write a line of code that will convert that string into a integer/double (w/e is appropriate)

Comment: Glad to hear it's working well, but I'm not familiar with parsing. Maybe someone else can jump in to help.

Comment: double UserIncome = Double.parseDouble(userIncome);  The variable 'userIncome' is in the parseDouble method, from the class Double, which will convert inputted strings to a double value, and save it in the UserIncome variable of type Double. You can also use int UserIncome = Integer.parseInt(userIncome);  for integers  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter your income: ");
    String userIncome=sc.nextLine();       

    calculateAndPrintTax(userIncome);
}       

static void calculateAndPrintTax(String userIncome)
{

    double uIncome= Double.parseDouble(userIncome);
    double federalExemption= 11327.0;
    double provincialExemption= 9863.0;
    double federalTax =  (uIncome- federalExemption) * 0.15;
    double provincialTax= (uIncome - provincialExemption) * 0.0505;
    double totalTax= federalTax + provincialTax;

    System.out.println("Your payable Federal tax is: " + federalTax);
    System.out.println("Your payable Provincial tax is: "+ provincialTax);
    System.out.println("Total payable tax is: "+ totalTax);
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. i'll post my beginning code I started off with

Comment: I made those changes, it helped, however there's another issue. I changed calculateAndPrintTax(userIncome); to 'uIncome'

Comment: Everything is fine as of now, except one thing, calculateAndPrintTax(uIncome);   within the main method, the 'uIncome' in underlined red and it says "possible lossy conversion from double to int"

Comment: I do not have enough room/characters to post new code in the 'Add Comment' section...Where would I post my new code? Im a newb :- |

Comment: Thanks for the help Faraz, what do you do? Do you come onto this site to answer questions for fun or is it your job